# Hiding tags with specific class in <iframe> using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, tableau-api

I need to upload an embedded visual template (created in Tableau) using `<iframe>` so that a client can view it live. However, at the bottom of the Tableau template, there are a few buttons (specifically, "Share", "Remember my changes", and "Edit" [[see screenshot here]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0zTK.jpg)) that I'd like to hide because it's not relevant to the client; I still would like to keep the rest of the buttons such as "Export", "Refresh" etc. on the same toolbar though.

I found out that the element that wraps these buttons is `<span class="tab-fill-left">`

[image: see screenshot here]

Which is nested heavily inside multiple `<iframe>`'s and other HTML tags. My original idea was to append a `<script>` tag like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
document.getElementsByClassName("tab-fill-left").style.display = "none"; 
alert('hello');
</script>
```

right after the `<iframe>` (below) that I have to enter to the system at my company to embed the data visualization page.

```
<iframe id="tableau_content" src="https://tableau-proxy.insidemedia.net/?site_id=MyCompanyProject&tableau_view=/views/MyCompanyEdition/Home%3F:embed=Yes%26:tabs=No%26:toolbar=Yes%26:display_share=No"  width=100%" height="100%" style="border: none; ">
</iframe>
```

But the JavaScript that I appended seem to have no effect whatsoever when the page is reloaded. Is there a way to influence elements that appear under `<iframe>` by appending another Javascript tag right after it? Or is there a way for me to hide these "Share", "Remember my changes" and "Edit" buttons in Tableau? It seems like [there are a few people](https://community.tableau.com/thread/118773) who run into the same issue using Tableau in this context and whatever they suggested there didn't work for me (I use Tableau 8.x as required by my employer).

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the page loaded inside the iframe is not in the same domain as the the parent frame, then it's not possible using JavaScript or CSS.

This is a security feature implemented on web browsers to prevent XSS (Cross site scripting).

Comment: Ah..I was confused why my simple JS code won't get executed... Thank you for clarifying this. :)

Answer (score 3):

Well, even in same domain this won't work:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("tab-fill-left").style.display = "none";
```

The above gives a `HTMLCollection`. So you need to do:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("tab-fill-left")[0].style.display = "none";
//----------------------------------------------^^^
```

Hope you understand.